# How to get Max value from list, but if there are 2 or more same value record then get all

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of key and value for ex:-

```
Key Value
21   2
23   1
24   2
```

i want max value record which i can get in linq with max(x=>x.value), but here in my case 21 and 24 both have max value and in this type of case means when there are 2 or more key have same max value then i want all of them how can i get expected result.

Please Give me hint or idea.

Regards,
vinit Patel

Comment: I've read this a couple of times and I still don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean sum of Key,Value should be max?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list like this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> keyValues = ...
```

You can group by value, then select the group with the max key:

```
var keys = keyValues.GroupBy(kv => kv.Value)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .Select(kv => kv.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
 var keyvalue = list.GroupBy(x => x.Value)             // Group on value
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)     // Order the group and 
                    .First()                           // Take first item in a group 
                    .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Key)       // Sort and get max Key,value combination.  
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tDgoLT)

Comment: `Select(x=>x)` doesn't do anything and can always be removed.

Comment: True, Removed it. Thanks @juharr

Comment: @juharr: Actually that is not *quite* true. Consider: `var a = new List<int>() { whatever } ; var b = a.Select(x=>x);` Plainly `a` and `b` have very different semantics; for one thing, you can call `Add` on `a` but not on `b`. The rule actually is that you can safely remove `Select(x=>x)` only when the receiver of the select is *already a query*. That's why the C# compiler will generate `a.Select(x=>x)` for `from x in a select x`, but will elide the `Select(x=>x)` in `from x in a where whatever select x`; since the result is known to be a query, the selection can be removed safely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```cs
var entries = new Dictionary<int, int>()
{
    {21, 2},
    {23, 1},
    {24, 2}
};

// First we select the max value.
int maxValue = entries.Max(kvp => kvp.Value);

// Or you can select the max value in this simpler way.
maxValue = entries.Values.Max();

// Then we select entries that have the max value.
var maxEntries =
    entries
        .Where(kvp => kvp.Value == maxValue)
        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```